# Combine info from two same-length lists

Tags: r, plyr, purrr

I have two lists (`l1` and `l2`) of length N and each item is a vector. I wish a new list of vectors from `l1` excluding indices in `l2`.

How can I avoid using a loop?

```
l1 <- list(a = c(5,2,9), b = c(4,7), c = c(1,3,1,9))
l2 <- list(a = 2, b = 1, c = c(1,3))
```

Output would look thus:

```
new.list <- list(a = c(5,9), b = 7, c = c(3,9))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` and remove index present in `l2` from `l1`

```
Map(function(x, y) x[-y], l1, l2)

#$a
#[1] 5 9

#$b
#[1] 7

#$c
#[1] 3 9
```

In `purrr` that can be done using `map2`

```
purrr::map2(l1, l2, ~.x[-.y])
```

Comment: Cheers @ronak-shah!

Comment: A good resource to learn `Map` is https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html